# WPF Child defined attached property initial value

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties

I would like to use an attached property to set properties of multiple child elements. Only during initialisation the `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)` returns 0 children.

When the binding MyText is changed after the view is rendered, all works as expected.

How can I itterate the children before rendering?

XAML:

```
<StackPanel local:SetTextService.Text="{Binding MyText}">
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
public class SetTextService : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
                           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text", typeof(string), typeof(SetTextService),
                           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(TextPropertyChanged)));

    public static void SetText(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetText(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    private static void TextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetChildControlText(d, (string)e.NewValue);
    }

    private static void SetChildControlText(DependencyObject parent, string text)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            PropertyInfo propInfo = child.GetType().GetProperty("Text");
            if (propInfo != null) propInfo.SetValue(child, text);
            SetChildControlText(child, text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attached property is set *before* the `TextBoxes` are added. You could either handle the `Loaded` event of the `StackPanel` and do the processing in this event handler instead of doing it in the property changed callback, or you can set your attached property *after* the `TextBoxes` have been added using the following element syntax:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <local:SetTextService.Text>
        <Binding Path="MyText" />
    </local:SetTextService.Text>
</StackPanel>
```

The order in which the properties are set matters.

Comment: Since the service can be used on more types than a StackPanel, using the second option solved my problem.